# How do I loop through Safari tabs?

Tags: objective-c, scripting, applescript

So I have this code that returns the current safari tab's URL

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAppleScript *script= [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"tell    application \"Safari\" to return URL of front document as string"];
    NSDictionary *scriptError = nil;
    NSAppleEventDescriptor *descriptor = [script    executeAndReturnError:&scriptError];
    if(scriptError) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",scriptError);
    } else {
        NSAppleEventDescriptor *unicode = [descriptor  coerceToDescriptorType:typeUnicodeText];
        NSData *data = [unicode data];
        NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:(unichar*)[data bytes] length:[data length] / sizeof(unichar)];
        NSLog(@"Result: %@",result);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I implement a loop to switch through all my tabs so it can output all the tab's URLs?

Answer (score 0):

This AppleScript code returns the URLs of all tabs

```
tell application "Safari" to return URL of tabs of window 1
```

The result is a list descriptor which must be converted to an `NSArray` object

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"tell application \"Safari\" to return URL of tabs of window 1"];
    NSDictionary *scriptError = nil;
    NSAppleEventDescriptor *descriptor = [script executeAndReturnError:&scriptError];
    if(scriptError) {
      NSLog(@"Error: %@",scriptError);
    } else {
      NSAppleEventDescriptor *listDescriptor = [descriptor  coerceToDescriptorType:typeAEList];
      NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      for (NSInteger i = 1; i <= [listDescriptor numberOfItems]; ++i) {
          NSAppleEventDescriptor *URLDescriptor = [listDescriptor descriptorAtIndex:i];
          [result addObject: URLDescriptor.stringValue];
      }

      NSLog(@"Result: %@", [result copy]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not what you want but here's a solution with Scripting Bridge:

```
SafariApplication *SafariApp = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.Safari"];
for (SafariWindow *window in SafariApp.windows)
{
    for (SafariTab *tab in window.tabs)
        NSLog(@"%@", tab.URL);
}
```